# We would like to hide Admin link if user that logged in is not an admin. Any ideas why my code isn't working?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

As you can see from markup below, there are 5 pages.

```
<ul>
<li><a href='Default.aspx'>Home</a></li>
<li><a href='vidpresentations.aspx'>Training Materials</a></li>
<li><a href='myAccount.aspx'>My Account</a></li>
<li class='selected'><a href='trainingPage.aspx'>Training Page</a></li>
<li runat="server" id="divAdmin"><span><a href='admin.aspx'>Administration</a></span></li>
</ul>
```

Then code behind on pageload() event sub:

```
If Session("UserRole") = 1 Then
    divAdmin.Visible = True
Else
    divAdmin.Visible = False
End If
```

Each page has the links shown in the markup.

One of those links is admin.aspx for our Administration page.

If a user logs in and his or her role is not that of an Administrator which is 1 then we would like to hide the Admin link.

I am not getting an error but the link is not being hidden.

If it is easier to disable the link, we wouldn't mind going that route.

Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Either step through with the debugger, or remove the 'if' statement and just set divAdmin.Visible = False - to make sure that is the line with the problem.   Perhaps your if statement isn't behaving like you think it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend setting the visibility of the control to false and then only displaying it if the user is detected as an admin. That way if there in an error like this, the link wouldn't be displayed for all users.

You can set the visiblilty default like this:

```
<li runat="server" visible="false"  id="divHideThis" >blerg</li>
```

Try this bit of code to write out the session variables and make sure that your `UserRole` varible is set and has a value you expect.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To Session.Contents.Count - 1
    Response.Write(Session.Keys(i) + " - " + Session(i) + "<br />")
Next

For Each key As String In Session.Keys
    Response.Write(key + " - " + Session(key) + "<br />")
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable may have to be cast to an int as the comparison could be of an object or string to the integer 1 which isn't likely the intended comparison.

IOW:

```
"1" = 1
```

Is likely going to be false.

Comment: This is VB, I don't think there is a == operator. = plays both roles.

Comment: That's weird, if I type == in the IDE, it shows an error. I'm certainly no expert, but I think that reference page you linked to is wrong. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/215yacb6(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I'm no VB expert, but suspect the Session("UserRole") needs casting to int

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
If Session("UserRole").ToString() = "1" Then
    divAdmin.Visible = True
Else
    divAdmin.Visible = False
End If
```

***For your other question:***

You can add *class* attribute to `li` tag

```
<li runat="server" id="divAdmin" class="hide">...</li>
```

where *hide = visibility: hidden* to make it initially hidden and then can make it visible at `Page_Load` with

```
li.Attributes("class") = "show"
```

where *show = visibility: visible* in your css.

Comment: So cast it to int and see if that works.  Have you proved which line of code isn't behaving as expected?

Comment: Ok, I look very stupid now. Please forgive me.

It actually works. Problem is that I am logging in as an admin. So, naturally, it will be visible.

The question I should be asking is, how do I make it initially hidden, preferrabley on markup and become visible with correct role.

I sincerely apologize.